How can I put node of a forest correctly?
This is my code I use almost to put edge label={node[midway,sloped]
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    anchor=north,
    child anchor=north,
    parent anchor=south,
    s sep+=1cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
},
[$\text{Start balls}$,
    [{$B$: "numbered balls"},edge label={node[midway,sloped, above]{$P(B)=\frac{5}{13}$}},
        [{$A$: ``Red ball and somethings''}, edge label={node[midway,sloped, below]{ $P(A|B)=\frac{3}{5}$}}, ]
        [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls and something'' }, edge label={node[midway, right]{$P(\overline{{A}}|B)=\frac{2}{5}$}}, ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''} ,edge label={node[midway,sloped, above]{$P(\overline{B})=\frac{8}{13}$}},
        [{$A$: ``red ball and somethings``}, edge label={node[midway, sloped]{$P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$}}, ]
        [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball and blue ball''}, edge label={node[midway,sloped, right]{$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=\frac{3}{8}$}}, ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

I get

and tried
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    anchor=north,
    child anchor=north,
    parent anchor=south,
    s sep+=1.5cm, % Adjusted vertical spacing
    l sep+=1cm, % Adjusted horizontal spacing
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}},
    font=\footnotesize % Reduced font size
},
[$\text{Start balls}$,
    [{$B$: "numbered balls"}, edge label={node[midway,sloped, above]{$P(B)=\frac{5}{13}$}},
        [{$A$: ``Red ball and somethings''}, edge label={node[midway,sloped, below]{ $P(A|B)=\frac{3}{5}$}}, ]
        [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls and something'' }, edge label={node[midway, right]{$P(\overline{{A}}|B)=\frac{2}{5}$}}, ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''}, edge label={node[midway,sloped, above]{$P(\overline{B})=\frac{8}{13}$}},
        [{$A$: ``red ball and somethings``}, edge label={node[midway, sloped]{$P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$}}, ]
        [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball and blue ball''}, edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=\frac{3}{8}$}}, ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document} 


How can I put node of a forest correctly and reduce this code?

so you want the edge labels to be sloped? do you also want to increase the level distance to make room for them? oh, they are sloped - there just isn't room?

It's not entirely clear what the intended result is. If you could explain that, it would be possible to provide an answer which might be more effective. In the absence of that, I took the main point to be ensuring everything could be read clearly. In that case, I'd recommend something like this:

\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, calc}
\forestset{%
  my edge label/.style n args=2{
    % Sašo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, left, #1] {#2}}{node [midway, right, #1] {#2}}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'+=.25cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
  },
  [$\text{Start balls}$,
    [{$B$: "numbered balls"},my edge label={above,pos=.25}{$P(B)=\frac{5}{13}$},
      [{$A$: ``Red ball and somethings''}, my edge label={}{ $P(A|B)=\frac{3}{5}$}, ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls and something'' }, my edge label={}{$P(\overline{{A}}|B)=\frac{2}{5}$}, ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''} ,my edge label={above,pos=.25}{$P(\overline{B})=\frac{8}{13}$},
      [{$A$: ``red ball and somethings``}, my edge label={}{$P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$}, ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball and blue ball''}, my edge label={}{$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=\frac{3}{8}$}, ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

Alternatively, if you increase the l sep significantly more, especially for the lower edges, you can accommodate the edge labels. For example,

\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, calc}
\forestset{%
  my edge label/.style n args=2{
    % Sašo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, sloped, left, #1] {#2}}{node [midway, sloped, right, #1] {#2}}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'+=.75cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
  },
  where level=1{l sep'+=1cm}{},
  [$\text{Start balls}$,
    [{$B$: "numbered balls"},my edge label={above}{$P(B)=\frac{5}{13}$},
      [{$A$: ``Red ball and somethings''}, my edge label={above}{ $P(A|B)=\frac{3}{5}$}, ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls and something'' }, my edge label={above}{$P(\overline{{A}}|B)=\frac{2}{5}$}, ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''} ,my edge label={above}{$P(\overline{B})=\frac{8}{13}$},
      [{$A$: ``red ball and somethings``}, my edge label={above}{$P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$}, ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball and blue ball''}, my edge label={above}{$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=\frac{3}{8}$}, ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

However, you might want to break the node texts into lines to avoid the tree ending up so wide.

I am sorry because too late to answer for you. First, thank you very much for your answer. Can you put edge labels to be sloped like my screenshot?

And you can change the orient of forest.

How can I increase distance between two rows?

@Laurenso please see edit.

Another possibilities: with a wee bit more simple and shorter code:
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw, rounded corners,
    minimum size=7mm, 
    outer sep=0pt,
    anchor=north,
    edge={draw, -Stealth},
where level=1{l sep'=23mm}{l sep'=8mm,},
  },
    EL/.style = {edge label={node[font=\small, midway, above, sloped] {#1}}},
%
[Start balls
    [{$B$: "numbered balls"},EL={$P(B)=\frac{5}{13}$},
        [{$A$: ``Red ball and somethings''}, EL={$P(A|B)=\frac{3}{5}$}]
        [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls and something'' }, 
EL={$P(\overline{{A}}|B)=\frac{2}{5}$} ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''}, EL={$P(\overline{B})=\frac{8}{13}$}
        [{$A$: ``red ball and somethings``}, EL={$P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$}]
        [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball and blue ball''}, EL={$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=\frac{3}{8}$}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}



Can I break line (use \ ) in  ractangles? Please consider this case grow = east

@Laurenso, yes  but in this case you need to forest specification add option align=center (or align=left, depends on how you like to have aligned nodes contents).

@Laurenso you can do this in your original code as you had align=center, which is essentially a tabular with a single column c.
