Display frac form in Forest automatically?
Based on this answer, I tried
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, calc}
\forestset{%
  my edge label/.style n args=2{
    % Sašo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, sloped, left, #1] {#2}}{node [midway, sloped, right, #1] {#2}}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'+=2.5cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
  },
  where level=1{l sep'+=1.5cm}{},
  [$\text{Start balls}$,
    [{$B$: ``numbered balls"},my edge label={above}{$P(B)=\frac{5}{13}$},
      [{$A$: ``Red ball\\ and somethings''}, my edge label={above}{ $P(A|B)=\frac{3}{5}$}, ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls\\ and something'' }, my edge label={above}{$P(\overline{{A}}|B)=1-\frac{3}{5} =\frac{2}{5} $}, ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''} ,my edge label={above}{$P(\overline{B})=1-\frac{5}{13}=\frac{8}{13}$},
      [{$A$: ``red ball\\ and somethings''}, my edge label={above}{$P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$}, ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball\\ and blue ball''}, my edge label={above}{$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=1-\frac{5}{8}=\frac{3}{8}$}, ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document} 

and get

How can I get the results 8/13 at $P(\overline{B})=1-\frac{5}{13}=\frac{8}{13}$
2/5 at $P(\overline{{A}}|B)=1-\frac{3}{5} =\frac{2}{5} $} and 3/8 at
$P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=1-\frac{5}{8}=\frac{3}{8}$
automatically without calculating by hand?
Can I input
$P(\overline{B})=1-P(B)$ and get $P(\overline{B})=1-P(B)= \frac{8}{13}$?

you could, but you don't really need to. and the less markup in the input, the better. also, to do this you don't want to be putting this into a label, you want to use forest options, so the markup will look a bit different. something like prob={B}{5}{13} for the relevant node and then nothing for the other one would be easiest. would that work?

can I assume the tree is binary i.e. you're always going to have one branch with p and the other with ~p, so exactly two children for every parent?

the link points to the question, by the way, so it isn't obvious which of the answers. (I would correct it, but then I'd be linking to my own answer.)

The following assumes all parents have exactly two children i.e. pairs of events are always mutually exclusive and exhaustive.
Given that condition, the following syntax is provided:

auto calc tree a forest style which should be added to the tree's preamble, as required;
prob={<event>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>} a node option which should be specified for at most one of any pair of siblings:

<event> should be the 'positive' case i.e. the one where you don't want the calculation e.g. B or \textrm{toast lands buttered side down};
<numerator> and denominator should be positive integers.



Auto-construction of values for siblings depends on those siblings having neither prob nor edge label. If either is specified, the construction of the edge label will be skipped.
ALL nodes besides the root node are subject to auto-construction of the edge label. Full specifications of events for conditional cases should not be given explicitly for any node as they will be constructed from the node's event value and the event values of any ancestors (bar root).
Construction takes place in three stages:

Step through the root's descendants. If event is empty for a node, but non-empty for its sibling, assign the sibling's event to the node, but negate it. So we get e.g. B and \overline{B} for the root's children and A/\overline{A} for all the grandchildren.
 for descendants={%
   if = { > O_= O_=! & {event}{} {!s.event}{} }
   {event/.process={ O w {!s.event}{\overline{##1}}}}{},
 },


For each of the descendants, we trace its ancestors, adding previous events at each stage. We don't use parentheses if we've just got a single event, otherwise we do, but we always add |. We save this into a node option named pre. So, for each node, pre ends up holding all the previous events in the node's history. For the children, this is empty. For the grandchildren, it is either |B or |\overline{B}.
 for descendants={%
   temptoksa={},
   for nodewalk={%
     while nodewalk valid={parent}{%
       parent,
       if level>=2 {
         temptoksa+={|(},
         temptoksa+/.option=event,
         temptoksa+={)},
       }{
         if level=1 {
           temptoksa+={|},
           temptoksa+/.option=event,
         }{},
       },
     }%
   }{},
   pre/.register=temptoksa,


Finally, we construct the edge labels from the values given to prob, combined with pre or from the assigned event, the accumulated pre and the values given as numerator and denominator to the node's sibling. This gives us e.g. $P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{5}{8}$ and $P(\overline{A}|\overline{B})=1-\frac{5}{8}=\frac{3}{8}$ for the third and fourth grandchildren respectively.
 for descendants ={
   if = { > O_= On= On=! && {edge label}{} {numer}{-1} {!s.numer}{-1} }% note this fails if edge label is specified, prob is specified or the sibling's prob isn't specified
    {
       numer/.option=!s.denom,
       numer-/.option=!s.numer,
       my edge label/.process={%
         OOOOOw5 {event}{numer}{!s.denom}{!s.numer}{pre}
         {%
           $P(\overline{##1}##5)=1-\frac{##4}{##3}=\frac{##2}{##3}$
         }%
       },
     }{



This isn't really careful enough. We should check edge label isn't specified and prob is. This would be easy to add, if required. You just need a simplified version of the test above i.e. don't check the sibling. So two conditions rather than three. Another option would be to do the edge label check first and then do two checks for the first case and just check prob is specified for the false branch.
          my edge label/.process={%
            OOOOw4 {event}{numer}{denom}{pre}
            {%
              $P(##1 ##4)=\frac{##2}{##3}$
            }%
          },
        },
      },


Complete code:
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% cwestiwn Laurenso gwreiddiol : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/724880/
% ateb gyntaf : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724883/
% ail gwestiwn : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725026/
% ail ateb : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725028/
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  my edge label/.style ={
    % Sašo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, sloped, left, above] {#1}}{node [midway, sloped, right, above] {#1}}
  },
  declare count={numer}{-1},
  declare count={denom}{-1},
  declare toks={event}{},
  declare toks={pre}{},
  prob/.style n args=3{%
    event={#1},
    numer=#2,
    denom=#3,
  },
  auto calc tree/.style={%
    delay = {%
      for descendants={%
        if = { > O_= O_=! & {event}{} {!s.event}{} }
        {event/.process={ O w {!s.event}{\overline{##1}}}}{},
      },
      delay = {%
        for descendants={%
          temptoksa={},
          for nodewalk={%
            while nodewalk valid={parent}{%
              parent,
              if level>=2 {
                temptoksa+={|(},
                temptoksa+/.option=event,
                temptoksa+={)},
              }{
                if level=1 {
                  temptoksa+={|},
                  temptoksa+/.option=event,
                }{},
              },
            }%
          }{},
          pre/.register=temptoksa,
        },
        delay = {%
          for descendants ={
            if = { > O_= On= On=! && {edge label}{} {numer}{-1} {!s.numer}{-1} }
            {
              numer/.option=!s.denom,
              numer-/.option=!s.numer,
              my edge label/.process={%
                OOOOOw5 {event}{numer}{!s.denom}{!s.numer}{pre}
                {%
                  $P(##1##5)=1-\frac{##4}{##3}=\frac{##2}{##3}$
                }%
              },
            }{
              my edge label/.process={%
                OOOOw4 {event}{numer}{denom}{pre}
                {%
                  $P(##1 ##4)=\frac{##2}{##3}$
                }%
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'+=2.5cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
  },
  where level=1{l sep'+=1.5cm}{},
  auto calc tree,
  [$\text{Start balls}$
    [{$B$: ``numbered balls"}, prob={B}{5}{13}
      [{$A$: ``Red ball\\ and somethings''}, prob={A}{3}{5}  ]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow balls\\ and something'' } ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Unnumbered balls''}
      [{$A$: ``red ball\\ and somethings''}, prob={A}{5}{8}]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Yellow ball\\ and blue ball''}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

1This is not going to work.

Can I use this?
[$\text{\b\, blue balls and \a\, red balls}$     [{$B$: ``Take one red ball"}, prob={B}{\a}{\ab}       [{$A$: ``Take one red ball\\ and another red ball''}, prob={A}{\a-1}{\ab-1}]       [{$\overline{A}$: ``Take one red ball\\ and one blue ball''} ]     ]     [{$\overline{B}$: ``Take one blue ball''}       [{$A$: ``One blue ball\\ and another blue ball''}, prob={A}{\a}{\ab-1}]       [{$\overline{A}$: ``One blue ball\\and another blue ball''}]     ]   ] \end{forest}

\begin{document} \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{5} \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{7} \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{\a + \b} \begin{forest}
