Where to put \pgfmathsetmacro into forest is correct and get highest efficiency?
Based on this answer, I put
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{37}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{73}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{\a + \b}

before \begin{forest}. My code
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% cwestiwn Laurenso gwreiddiol : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/724880/
% ateb gyntaf : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724883/
% ail gwestiwn : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725026/
% ail ateb : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725028/
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  my edge label/.style ={
    % Sašo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, sloped, left, above] {#1}}{node [midway, sloped, right, above] {#1}}
  },
  declare count={numer}{-1},
  declare count={denom}{-1},
  declare toks={event}{},
  declare toks={pre}{},
  prob/.style n args=3{%
    event={#1},
    numer=#2,
    denom=#3,
  },
  auto calc tree/.style={%
    delay = {%
      for descendants={%
        if = { > O_= O_=! & {event}{} {!s.event}{} }
        {event/.process={ O w {!s.event}{\overline{##1}}}}{},
      },
      delay = {%
        for descendants={%
          temptoksa={},
          for nodewalk={%
            while nodewalk valid={parent}{%
              parent,
              if level>=2 {
                temptoksa+={|(},
                temptoksa+/.option=event,
                temptoksa+={)},
              }{
                if level=1 {
                  temptoksa+={|},
                  temptoksa+/.option=event,
                }{},
              },
            }%
          }{},
          pre/.register=temptoksa,
        },
        delay = {%
          for descendants ={
            if = { > O_= On= On=! && {edge label}{} {numer}{-1} {!s.numer}{-1} }
            {
              numer/.option=!s.denom,
              numer-/.option=!s.numer,
              my edge label/.process={%
                OOOOOw5 {event}{numer}{!s.denom}{!s.numer}{pre}
                {%
                  $P(##1##5)=1-\frac{##4}{##3}=\frac{##2}{##3}$
                }%
              },
            }{
              my edge label/.process={%
                OOOOw4 {event}{numer}{denom}{pre}
                {%
                  $P(##1 ##4)=\frac{##2}{##3}$
                }%
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{37}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{73}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{\a + \b}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'+=2.8cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
  },
  where level=1{l sep'+=1.5cm}{},
  auto calc tree,
  [$\text{\b\, blue balls and \a\, red balls}$
    [{$B$: ``Take one red ball"}, prob={B}{\a}{\ab}
      [{$A$: ``Take one red ball\\ and another red ball''}, prob={A}{\a-1}{\ab-1}]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Take one red ball\\ and one blue ball''} ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Take one blue ball''}
      [{$A$: ``One blue ball\\ and another blue ball''}, prob={A}{\a}{\ab-1}]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``One blue ball\\and another blue ball''}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

I get

I see the result is correct.
Can I  put
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{37}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{73}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{\a + \b}

outside \begin{forest} \end{forest}?
Where can I put \pgfmathsetmacro to get the correct result and highest efficiency?

could you say why you wan to use \pgfmathsetmacro? what I would do here is redo the style so you can input the stuff using forest's key-value syntax and get the result you want. but I'm not sure whether that would answer your question.

I think, it can caculate to probabilities based on your answer.

I'm surprised it doesn't give an error. it's basically an expansion issue. the assignment to count registers just absorbs the argument. it doesn't run it through pgfmath first. it's basically TeX rather than tikz.

apart from pgf issues, as you were told previously in chat it's a bad idea to over-write standard latex commands such as \a and \b you should use different names.

@DavidCarlisle A bad idea, is it true?

\documentclass{article} \def\c{6} \begin{document} Français \end{document}  for example, you get no error but latex is broken.

I already told you at least twice, but @DavidCarlisle says it and you still don't believe it??!!

@cfr I believe it.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you very much.

I don't know why you would want to do this, but here is a (fairly inefficient) way to make it work.
pgfmath and 'highest efficiency' are mutually exclusive. pgfmath is extremely slow. It is highly tolerant in the input it accepts, but this has its price. So I've focused on the 'correct' (incorrect) result and ignored the efficiency desideratum.
We make several changes to prob, the tree and the definitions.

We change prob to run the second and third argument through pgfmath.
prob/.style n args=3{%
  event={#1},
  numer/.pgfmath={#2},
  denom/.pgfmath={#3},
},


We change the names of the macros to avoid overwriting LaTeX commands.
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\anum}{37}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\bnum}{73}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\abnum}{\anum + \bnum}%


We use int in the definition of \abnum to ensure an integer.
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\abnum}{int(\anum + \bnum)}%


We also need int in the second and third argument of prob when calculating e.g. prob={A}{\anum}{int(\abnum-1)}.


Note that if you have many or complex trees, unnecessary use of pgfmath increases compilation time significantly. This is why prooftrees was rewritten to use the argument processor: it enables the code to push as much as possible onto TeX.
Anyway, here is the mathematically dubious result:

\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% cwestiwn Laurenso gwreiddiol : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/724880/
% ateb gyntaf : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724883/
% ail gwestiwn : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725026/
% ail ateb : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725028/
% cwestiwn minhthien_2016 : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725069/
% trydedd ateb : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725082/
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  my edge label/.style ={
    % Sašo: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34010033#34010033
    edge label/.process={On=?}{n}{1}{node [midway, sloped, left, above] {#1}}{node [midway, sloped, right, above] {#1}}
  },
  declare count={numer}{-1},
  declare count={denom}{-1},
  declare toks={event}{},
  declare toks={pre}{},
  prob/.style n args=3{%
    event={#1},
    numer/.pgfmath={#2},
    denom/.pgfmath={#3},
  },
  auto calc tree/.style={%
    delay = {%
      for descendants={%
        if = { > O_= O_=! & {event}{} {!s.event}{} }
        {event/.process={ O w {!s.event}{\overline{##1}}}}{},
      },
      delay = {%
        for descendants={%
          temptoksa={},
          for nodewalk={%
            while nodewalk valid={parent}{%
              parent,
              if level>=2 {
                temptoksa+={|(},
                temptoksa+/.option=event,
                temptoksa+={)},
              }{
                if level=1 {
                  temptoksa+={|},
                  temptoksa+/.option=event,
                }{},
              },
            }%
          }{},
          pre/.register=temptoksa,
        },
        delay = {%
          for descendants ={
            if = { > O_= On= On=! && {edge label}{} {numer}{-1} {!s.numer}{-1} }
            {
              numer/.option=!s.denom,
              numer-/.option=!s.numer,
              my edge label/.process={%
                OOOOOw5 {event}{numer}{!s.denom}{!s.numer}{pre}
                {%
                  $P(##1##5)=1-\frac{##4}{##3}=\frac{##2}{##3}$
                }%
              },
            }{
              my edge label/.process={%
                OOOOw4 {event}{numer}{denom}{pre}
                {%
                  $P(##1 ##4)=\frac{##2}{##3}$
                }%
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\anum}{37}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bnum}{73}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\abnum}{int(\anum + \bnum)}%
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    l sep'+=2.8cm,
    edge={draw, -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
  },
  where level=1{l sep'+=1.5cm}{},
  auto calc tree,
  [$\text{\bnum{} blue balls and \anum{} red balls}$
    [{$B$: ``Take one red ball"}, prob={B}{\anum}{\abnum}
      [{$A$: ``Take one red ball\\ and another red ball''}, prob={A}{int(\anum-1)}{int(\abnum-1)}]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``Take one red ball\\ and one blue ball''} ]
    ]
    [{$\overline{B}$: ``Take one blue ball''}
      [{$A$: ``One blue ball\\ and another blue ball''}, prob={A}{\anum}{int(\abnum-1)}]
      [{$\overline{A}$: ``One blue ball\\and another blue ball''}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

